# Sanctity of a holy, sacred, saint [someone/something]

Tags: word-usage

This question ["Difference between saint, holy and sacred"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126405/difference-between-saint-holy-and-sacred) has made me think whether we can use the noun **"sanctity"** to speak about things or people that/who are already **holy**, **sacred**, or **saint**.

For instance:

- The sanctity of this sacred temple has attracted many tourists.
- The scripts in this holy book are sanctity to the keepers of the library.
- The sanctity of the saint brings them closer to church.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The word "sanctity" refers to the holiness of something as per the [following google definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sanctity):

> the state or quality of being holy, sacred, or saintly.

So it can only be used for something that is already holy, sacred, or saintly; it wouldn't make sense any other way.

As a brief aside, your example `The scripts in this holy book are sanctity to the keepers of the library` uses the word incorrectly, unless i'm very much mistaken.  Though "sanctity" is a noun, nothing can *be* sanctity, in the same way that nothing can be *holiness*— only holy.  Words with the *-ness* suffix refer to the quality itself, and you cannot *be* the quality: you can only possess it.

Comment: unless we were to say "... are sanctity itself..." meaning more or less that "these books are for them the pinnacle of holiness"